# How to test routes in apache camel (spring)

Tags: java, spring, apache, apache-camel

This is my system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <import resource="jetty.xml" />
    <import resource="communication.xml" />

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
        id="camel">
        <route> 
        <from uri="file://test.json"/>
            <threads>
                <bean ref="operationTest" method="test" />
            </threads>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Here is my communication.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="operationTest" class="edu.test.Test">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have a main of

```
    context = new SpringServerContext(new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("conf/system.xml"));

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(group, new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            stop();
        }

    }, shutdownThreadName));
    context.startup();
```

and the Test class has a method of

```
    public Object test(Object info) {
//prints info
}
```

Yet when I run, nothing prints. . .

Can we not trigger the from tag by a file?

I am also trying from Active MQ and is not succeding getting an error of

because of No endpoint could be found for: brokerURL, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used Active MQ for the route and it worked